# Gamma GLMM in R with unusual data format

Tags: generalized-linear-model, glmm

I have been trying to find how hummingbirds' behaviors and sex correlate to the interval between their vocalizations. The intervals have a non-normal distribution. Each observation is not independent (some hummingbirds have been sampled multiple times without note). I have tried to analyze the data with a GLM but I do not think this model is sufficient due to its assumption of independence. Within my dataset, there is one continuous dependent variable (interval) and several categorical independent variables. Below is some mock data showing the layout. I am not sure how to code GLMMs and could not find much info on gamma GLMMS I can link the data sheet if needed. Thanks so much!

| File | Avg Interval | Sex | Feeding Behavior | Territorial Behavior | Mobility |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.wav | 0.3291110000000 | Male | Not Feeding | None | Perching |
| 2.wav | 0.48777777777777 | Female | Feeding | Confrontation | Perching&Flying |
| 3.wav | 0.22222244444111 | Unknown | Not Feeding | Chasing | Flying |
| 4.wav | 0.65611111111111111 | Male | Feeding | Unknown | Perching&Flying |
| 5.wav | 0.77777222222222 | Unknown | Not Feeding | Singing | Perching |